# Flutter web app Japanese Character(Non English Character) doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter-web, flutter-hotreload

I am going to write flutter web in vs code.
Before creating a flutter app, I already feed following commands.

```
flutter channel beta

flutter upgrade

flutter config --enable-web
```

After that I create a flutter web app via

```
vsCode > Shift+Command+P > Flutter:New Application Project
```

I added some Japanese and Arab text in generated sample code after creating a new flutter web app.
Japanese Text are not shown when I running with Shift+F5 or F5.

[image]

Japanese and Arab Text are displayed if I run from terminal with following command.

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

But this doesn't work hot reload if I don't press 'r' or 'R' in terminal again.

Is there anyone who is facing that problem and have solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When launching Flutter project by pressing F5, [**dartdevc**](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdevc) compiler is used, but command `flutter run -d chrome` uses [**dart2js**](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js) compiler.

**dartdevc** renders text on canvas HTML-element (with *CanvasKit*) and uses system fonts.

**dart2js** renders text as paragraph HTML-element, and therefore uses fonts from browser.

As a workaround, you can use [a custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts), for example [Noto Sans JP](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP).

There is related [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53897).

Comment: It works well with Custom Font. thanks for your answer.